# I am confused about the tense and the sentence structure here

Tags: tense, sentence-structure, future-tense

> If I couldn't get out of it could she come with me?

> If I can't get out of it can she come with me?

Which sentence is correct as I want to use for if condition talking about future?

Answer (score 0):

For the "if" clause, use "can".  Here the meaning of "can" is "be able" and you want to use the non-past form to talk about the future.

For the second part there is a difference in meaning.  We can use "can" to mean "is she able (or permitted) to come with me"  But "could" is also used to mean "is it possible that..." Using "could" is more 'tentative', so it might be useful if you are asking for a favour.   So for the second part both "can" and "could" may be used, with very similar meanings.

> If I can't get out, could she come with me (is it, perhaps, possible for her to come with me...please)

> If I can't get out, can she come with me. (is she able and permitted to come with me)

Answer (score 0):

Both examples are valid. Can and could are [both used to express possibility in the present and the future](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/could). The difference is in [how likely it is that the hypothetical will be true](https://byjus.com/english/difference-between-can-and-could/).

"Can" is typically used to express something that's known or something that is  likely to be possible.

> If I can't get out of it, can she come with me?

"Could" is used to express a weaker possibility.

> If I couldn't get out of it, could she come with me?

The possibility of "getting out of it" is more likely with "can" than with "could".